# Vega 56 drivers, missing firmware

Tags: linux, kernel, amd-graphics

In void linux kernel 4.13.3_1 I'm having trouble getting the amdgpu drivers to work.

Relevant output from dmesg:

```
[    0.944960] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    0.945421] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (VEGA10 0x1002:0x687F 0x1002:0x6B76 0xC3).
[    0.945426] [drm] register mmio base: 0xED400000
[    0.945426] [drm] register mmio size: 524288
[    0.945450] amdgpu 0000:44:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/vega10_gpu_info.bin failed with error -2
[    0.945450] amdgpu 0000:44:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    1.951031] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3393.622 MHz
[    1.951217] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x30eac5b3ab4, max_idle_ns: 440795272524 ns
[    2.959338] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   62.431041] amdgpu 0000:44:00.0: Failed to load gpu_info firmware "amdgpu/vega10_gpu_info.bin"
[   62.431110] amdgpu 0000:44:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init
[   62.431170] [drm] amdgpu: finishing device.
[   62.431170] [TTM] Memory type 2 has not been initialized
[   62.431668] amdgpu: probe of 0000:44:00.0 failed with error -11
```

I'm building without initramfs. I cannot find the the amdgpu folder below /lib/modules, but it might be because they are included in the kernel.

Some kernel settings:

```
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU=y
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_SI=y
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_CIK=y
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_USERPTR=y
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_GART_DEBUGFS=y
```

Have checked "Include in-kernel firmware blobs in kernel binary".

I have `linux-firmware` installed from xbps.

Edit: I have `amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1` added to the kernel parameters.

Comment: Is there an `amdgpu` directory in `/lib/firmware`? (That’s where it’s supposed to be.)

Comment: Yes there is. There is no file with vega in it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [the firmware files](https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vega10/) for your GPU and copy them to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`. The kernel should then be able to load them.

Comment: I tried copying them and rebooting but I'm getting the same errors. Do I need to do something else? Also, any idea why I need to do this manually?

Comment: I noticed the link you provided links to a `radeon_ucode` folder. I found another link https://github.com/wkennington/linux-firmware/tree/master/amdgpu with vega bins under `amdgpu`, but sadly with the same results.

Comment: You’re still getting `Failed to load gpu_info firmware "amdgpu/vega10_gpu_info.bin"`? (I suggested doing this manually because the files are very recent, perhaps not packaged for your distribution, and I don’t know your distribution anyway so I don’t know where to look. We can figure that out later, once we get the firmware loading...)

Comment: Yes it's still failing to load gpu_info, with the other errors as well. Alright, makes sense in getting it to load first.